# view on dialog doesn't change when it should

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, layout-inflater

I have a `ListView` that when an item is being clicked its create new PlaySongAlertDialog object and passes params to it. Now the problem at the following code is that only at first time its actually changes the text of `artistCheckBox` and when i click dismiss and then on another `ListView` row its show me the same text on `artistCheckBox`.
 I can't find the post but i remember that someone said that i should override `onPrepareDialog` but i cant find such method on `AlertDialog.Builder` class.

```
public class PlaySongAlertDialog extends AlertDialog.Builder {
    public PlaySongAlertDialog(final Context context, final String songName, final Intent service) {
        super(context);
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View dialoglayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.download_song_alert_dialog_check_box, null);
        final CheckBox artistCheckBox = (CheckBox) dialoglayout.findViewById(R.id.artist_checkbox);
        final CheckBox albumCheckBox = (CheckBox) dialoglayout.findViewById(R.id.album_checkbox);
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try{
                    artistCheckBox.setText("Add artist name (" + getSomethingFromTheWeb.getArtist(songName) +")");
                } catch(Exception e){
                    artistCheckBox.setText("Add artist name (can't found)" );
                    artistCheckBox.setClickable(false);
                }

            }
        });
        thread.start();
        try {
            thread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        setMessage("Do you want to play: " + songName);
        setView(dialoglayout);
}
```

Also this is how i create new dialog (this code is on main activity)

```
DownloadSongAlertDialog dialog = new DownloadSongAlertDialog(this, name, serviceIntent);
dialog.show();
```

Is there a way to create a **real** dialog every time instead of reusing the last one, maybe clean the cache or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`thread.join();` is blocking the UI thread waiting for the other thread to finish. That's the reason why you don't see the dialog updating. To fix you could subclass `AsyncTask`, and start it in the constructor of your `AlertDialog`. When `onPostExecute` is invoked you fill up the `View` and show it.